# How do I get an image and a line of text to display inline with one another?

Tags: html, css

(See picture and code below)

I wanted the github logo and the text linking to the specific page to be nicely lined up with one another. How would I go about doing that?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xPPn.png)
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eleGU.png)

Tried putting it in a div class and a paragraph tag and neither worked. Also tried display-inline and changing the padding/margin around the text and image, which didn't work either.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hi Kaylee, please post a running [reprex]. And also explain what *you* mean with 'nicely lined up'. It is too ambiguous as various options may apply: vertical, horizontal, centered, top or bottom aligned. To name a few...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to `hompagecredits` CSS class:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
```